# Python fabric, why does grep fails using []

Tags: python, grep, fabric

I was wondering why I'm getting Fatal error while doing grep with [], looking for the logic here.

Working:

```
    In [37]: run("""ps aux | grep "grunt" """)
    [worker2] run: ps aux | grep "grunt" 
    [worker2] out: root     21414  0.0  0.0  16476  5632 pts/0    Ss+  03:10   0:00 /bin/bash -l -c ps aux | grep "grunt" 
    [worker2] out: root     21475  0.0  0.0  11752   884 pts/0    S+   03:10   0:00 grep grunt
    [worker2] out: 

    Out[37]: 'root     21414  0.0  0.0  16476  5632 pts/0    Ss+  03:10   0:00 /bin/bash -l -c ps aux | grep "grunt" \r\nroot     21475  0.0  0.0  11752   884 pts/0    S+   03:10   0:00 grep grunt'
```

not working:

```
    In [38]: run("""ps aux | grep "[g]runt" """)
    [worker2] run: ps aux | grep "[g]runt" 

    Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

    Requested: ps aux | grep "[g]runt" 
    Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "ps aux | grep \"[g]runt\" "

    Aborting.
    An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

    SystemExit: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
```

Any idea as to why the second verse is not working?

Comment: Have you tried single quotes? grep '[g]runt'

Comment: Forget single quotes, just see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the exit 1 that grep returns, put as this:

`grep "[g]runt" | tee`

This is due to grep doesn't find nothing literally when using square brackets (when grunt does really run, it should work, try it)